# Google datastore precondition fail with timestamps

Tags: node.js, gcloud, google-cloud-datastore, gcloud-node

Hello I am trying to query google datastore entries from the node.js api. I have an entity which has an owner (string), a start time (date time) and an end time (date time) I am trying to query for all entities which match the given owner string and start after a given date with the following function (es2016).

```
static async getAvailability (owner, month = currentMonth) {
    const firstOfMonth = moment([currentYear, month])
    const query = datastore.createQuery('availability')
      .filter('owner', '=', owner)
      .filter('end', '>', firstOfMonth.toDate().toJSON())
      .order('end', {
        descending: true
      })
    try {
      // promise version of run query same function
      const result = await datastore.runQueryAsync(query)
      return result.map(result => {
        const { key, data } = result
        data._id = key.id
        return data
      })
    } catch (e) {
      console.log('error', e.stack)
      return []
    }
}
```

index.yaml
    indexes

```
- kind: availability
  properties:
  - name: owner
  - name: start
    direction: desc
  - name: end
    direction: desc
```

I am getting the error precondition failed error when i run the query. If there is any more information i can provide I would be more than happy.

Comment: What line is the error occurring?

Comment: The error is occurring on `datastore.runRequest` so in this code line 11.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your query listed is only on `owner` and `end`. When you are using Cloud Datastore, the index you use has to exactly match the query.

In the case of the query you listed, you need the index:

```
- kind: availability
  properties:
  - name: owner
  - name: end
    direction: desc
```

If you actually wanted your start date to be a specific time, your filter would have to be:

```
  .filter('start', '>', firstOfMonth.toDate().toJSON())
```

And you [would have to specify it first](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/queries#properties_used_in_inequality_filters_must_be_sorted_first) in your orders:

```
 .order('start')
 .order('end', {
    descending: true
  })
```

Comment: I worked  I was confused about the index defining the query rather than the entity.